# Prove that $M_{n\times n}(K)$ and $P_{n^2-1}[x]$ are not isomorphic rings

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

Prove that $M_{n\times n}(K)$ and $P_{n^2-1}[x]$ (polynomials with degree less than or equal to $n^2-1$) are not isomorphic rings for any field $K$ and $n\ge 2$

Let $f: M_{n\times n}(K)\to P_{n^2-1}[x]$ a ring isomorphism. Let $A\in M_{n\times n}(K)$ so that $f(A)$ is not the zero polynomial: $f(AI_n)=f(A)f(I_n)$ but $AI_n=A$ hence $f(A)=f(A)f(I_n)\Rightarrow 1=f(I_n)$

But since $f$ is any ring isomorphism then I don't what polynomial is $f(I_n)$. Is this the correct approach? I would really appreciate if you can help me :)

Comment: This doesn't help much. $I_n$ is the multiplicative identity, hence must map to the multiplicative identity in the polynomial ring, i.e. the constant 1. This is always the case.

Comment: How is $P_{n^2-1}[K]$ a ring? What is $X^{n^2-1} \times X$?

Comment: How is multiplication defined in $P_{n^2-1}[K]$? Modulo $X^{n^2}$ or modulo $X^{n^2}-1$? If it s the former: Note that $A^k=0$ for a matrix $A$ and some integer $k$ implies $A^n=0$.

Comment: So the answer should be: they are not isomorphic rings, because they aren't both rings.

Comment: I hope that my answers clears up the confusion, which is not only on the side of the OP here ...

Comment: @Martin I don't see how you can be so sure it's $K[x]/(x^{n^2})$. That's likely (because the dimensions match if anything) and it was my first guess, but OP should clarify. It could very well be $K[x]/(x^{n^2}-1)$ for example (as Hagen suggests).

Comment: It's probably standard in some circles but not everywhere... I've always seen $K[x]/x^n$ written out in full. Besides the answer is so simple with that interpretation that it can be suspicious.

Comment: Anyway, polynomial algebras are commutative ...

Answer (score 2):

If $d \in \mathbb{N}$, then usually $P_d(x)$ means $K[x]/(x^{d+1})$, and is called a *truncated polynomial algebra*. This is a ring and it should *not* be confused with the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq d$. This is just (a version of) the underlying $K$-vector space. You cannot multiply polynomials of degree $\leq d$ to get polynomials of degree $\leq d$, but you can multiply in $P_d(x)$. (It is a common habit to ignore forgetful functors, but this here is one of lots examples where this is no good idea.)

In our case, $P_{n^2-1}(x) = K[x]/(x^{n^2})$. The underlying vector space has dimension $n^2$, which is also the dimension of $M_{n \times n}(K)$. Hence, the underlying vector spaces of $P_{n^2-1}(x)$ and $M_{n \times n}(K)$ are isomorphic.

But they are not isomorphic rings (when $n>1$), and there are many reasons for this. The simplest one is that $P_{n^2-1}(x)$ is commutative, and $M_{n \times n}(K)$ is not.